# fill a dropdownlistfor using jquery

Tags: jquery, dropdown, cascading, mvc

I m filling a (MANAGER)dropdownlistfor based on (DEPARTMENT)dropdownlistfor as follows. Using MVC mode SP O365 list. 
But I m not sure how to pass the selected value from Department dropdown to Manager dropdown.

```
  function onDepartmentChange() {
            var DepartmnetId = $("#Department option:selected").text();
            alert(+DepartmnetId);
           // alert("before");

            $.ajax({
                url: '@Url.Action("FillCity")',
                type: "POST",
                dataType: "JSON",
                contentType: 'application/json; charset=utf-8',
                data: {} ,
                success: function (result) {
                    $("#Manager").html("");
                    $.each($.parseJSON(result), function (i, city) {
                        $("#Manager").append
                        ($('<option></option>').val(city.CityID).html(city.CityName))
                    })
                },
                error: function () { alert("Something bad"); }
            });


 <div class="form-group">
                @Html.LabelFor(model => model.Department.Name, new { @class = "control-label col-md-2" })
                <div class="col-md-10">
                    @*Binding the choice field to dropdown list*@
                    @Html.DropDownListFor(model => model.Department.Name,
                   new SelectList(ViewBag.AllDepartments, "Department"),
                   "Select the Department", 
                   new { id = "Department", onchange="onDepartmentChange();" })                        
                    @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.Department.Name)
                </div>
            </div>

 <div class="form-group">
                @Html.LabelFor(m => m.Manager.ManagerName, new { @class = "control-label col-md-2" })
                <div class="col-md-10">
                    @Html.DropDownListFor(m => m.Manager.ManagerName,
                     new SelectList(Enumerable.Empty<SelectListItem>(), "UserId", "ManagerName"), "Select Manager" , new { id = "Manager" })
                    @Html.ValidationMessageFor(m => m.Manager.ManagerName, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
                </div>
            </div>
```

****Controller****

```
[HttpPost]
        public JsonResult FillCity(int depid=2)
        {

          //  var spContext = LocalLeaveAddinWeb.SharePointContextProvider.Current.GetSharePointContext(HttpContext);
            CamlQuery querySelectedDepartment = new CamlQuery();
            querySelectedDepartment.ViewXml = "<Where><Eq><FieldRef Name=\"Department_x003a_ID\" /><Value Type=\"Text\">" + depid + "</Value></Eq></Where>";
            List<Models.Department> Departments = SharePointService.GetSelectedDepManagers(spContext, querySelectedDepartment);

            return Json(**Departments**, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
        }  <------**HERE I M NOT SURE HOW TO PASS THE Departments VALUE**
```

Can someone please help me.

Answer (score 2):

You can use SPServices to Cascade your dropdown lists if they share a lookup relationship.

```
$().SPServices.SPCascadeDropdowns({
    relationshipList: "ManagerListName",
    relationshipListParentColumn: "Department",    
    relationshipListChildColumn: "Manager",
    parentColumn: "Department", //Internal name of the column
    childColumn: "Manager", //Internal name of the column
    debug: true
  });
```